# Can I access the header of a text content element?

Tags: filter, typo3, fluid, typo3-11.x

I need to get the headline and the text separately out of a text content element. The reason is, to give the editor a simple way to add a content for a complicated section in my html theme.

I am new to TYPO3 an we run V11.5.16! I read and watched some tutorials and I got most of my site already working! Contents are dynamic and multilinguale so far.

To get contents from backend, I use Backend Layouts and copy the content from styles.content.get inside my setup.typoscript. I think this is the common way to do it, and as I said, it works. I output them using `{contentXY->f:transform.html()}` or `{contentXY->f:format.raw()}`.

For a text content element, I get something like:

```xml
<div id="c270" class="frame frame-default frame-type-text frame-layout-0">
  <header>
    <h2 class="">Headline</h2>
  </header>
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get only "Headline"? And if so, it hopefully works also for getting out separately "Some Text"

Something like: `{contentXY->f:transform.html(filterBy('h2'))}`

Thanks in Advance!

EDIT:

According to Peter Krause's answer: I know, there is an extra content element for headers. But I need the text content element, because for the places in the html, I need header AND text. And the editors are technically not savy enough to fill in different content elements. Please don't ask in more detail. ):

Comment: You know that there is a content element of type "Headline"? Maybe that's all you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all hints! I think, for my requirement, there is no solution out of the box. So i made a custom CE with Mask and edited the template html. For non-technical editors, it is the best solution in terms of data input. I hope this stands for future upgrades...

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `header` and `body` of an CE seperately, but not in a page context.
In page context you get the result from rendering the CEs, which is a string (with HTML).

For each CE there is a rendering information, which nowadays is also FLUID.
Depending on your installation it probably is FSC (ext:fluid_styled_content) or a Bootstrap extension.
This means: there are FLUID templates which can be [overriden](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/11.5/en-us/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/Index.html) and modified.
In these templates you have access to each field of a CE separately.

Look for the templates stored in the defined paths (in TSOB) and add your own path for overides:

```
lib.contentElement {
   templateRootPaths {
      1 = ...
      2 = ...
      3 = ...your path...
   }
   partialRootPaths {
      1 = ...
      2 = ...
      3 = ...your path...
   }
   layoutRootPaths {
      1 = ...
      2 = ...
      3 = ...your path...
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that hint! I now made an override of the text-CE, which is very simple. And yes - you can access data.header and data.bodytext. But unfortunately, you have to output this into ONE string. So at last, in a page context, you get also a not-divideable string.

Comment: it sounds like you want a jump-navigation in the page to all the content elements consisting from all the headers of the CEs, while the header should not be shown where the body of the CEs is shown. There is a menu CE for the headers. You can redefine the menu to omit the links, and you can change the rendering of the CEs to omit the header. (anyway it sounds like your data structure doesn't fit your usage when you need to tear the data apart)

Comment: No, i wanted what i described :) I have an styled html element in my page. It contains a header und a couple of lines below, some text. I could give editors TWO CEs (A header CE and a Text CE) and put it in the right position of my html code. But as i described, for the editors, it has to be as simple as possible. Having two CEs (for each html element) is not a good solution. So i was looking for a solution to get the contents out of ONE CE and place it at the right position in the html code. I think there is only one good solution: Making a custom CE. This works fine for me and the editors!